# connecting two Android phones via WiFi using Access-Point

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I was doing some research and I want to develop an application to share files between two Android Phones 2.2, via WiFi using one Access Point on the same network.

Is it posible? in that case, what do i need?

Thanks a  lot,

Comment: If it's just 2 phones, why not use bluetooth?  I also recommend you consider using Bump's api: http://bu.mp/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually really easy to do. Grab a copy of:

http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/

This will allow one phone to find the other - then you can transfer any file between phones using sockets or http or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

- [AndFTP](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/) (Intents are available)
- [Swiftp](http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/)  - to create an FTP server
- Using a [FTP Client](http://hoang17.com/posts/android/android-how-to-upload-a-file-via-ftp) to upload to the server

To detect other android devices make the server multicast and all client listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Portable WiFi hotspot ...

Using that I just connected my HTC Explorer And Sony Ericsson Xperia neo v Through WiFi